# using a cast in an overriden equals method should I use generics and if so, how?

Tags: java, generics

here is my issue when trying to override my equals method.

this is what I have currently

```
 @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
 if (this.name.equals(((Animal) o).getName())) {
  System.out.println("True");
return true;
} else {
 System.out.println("False");
 return false;
 }

}
```

I'm trying to compare the names of objects which extend the Animal class is there a better way to create this equals method without the explicit casting to compare the names of each object?, I was messing around with Generics but just couldn't get it to work properly. below is what I attempted with generics but when I tried to pass an object in the parenthesis it was just using the super equals method. (The get method literally just returns the name)

```
public boolean equals(Class<? extends Animal>o) {
 if (this.name.equals(o.getName())) {
   System.out.println("True");
   return true;
} else {
   System.out.println("False");
   return false;
  }

}
```

any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review; however, there is not enough context here for us to provide a meaningful review, and this site is not the place to ask for help with producing working code. Please consult the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking), to find out how to make the most of this resource.

Comment: Ive edited the code, hopefully this meets the standards.

Comment: There isn't enough code here for us to give a good review, it might be better if you posted the entire class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like the following in The Animal Class:

```
 @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      Animal animal = null;
      if(obj == null || this ==null) {
         return false;
      }
      if(obj instanceof Animal) {
         animal = (Animal) obj;
      }
      if(this.name.equals(animal.getName())) {
         return true;
      }

      return super.equals(obj);
   }
```

Now if you have a Cat and a Dog which extend Animal
and you check

```
private Cat cat = new Cat("Pipsy");
private Dog dog = new Dog("Pupsy");
```

`if(cat.equals(dog))` will return false because you check the name, and they have a different one.

I do not think you have to use Generics, Object is generic enough :). Hope this helped

Comment: Ah this seems to be what I was looking for, thank you very much =)

Comment: This will cause a NPE if the `obj` is not an Animal. I'm surprised the compiler doesn't warn you about it

Comment: How could `this` ever be `null`?